# Fragment back navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have an AppCompatActivity with

```
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar myToolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.my_toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I use fragments in this activity to change what is displayed under the toolbar. I want each fragment (on `SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.content, myFragment).Commit()`) to be pushed on a stack so on toolbar back button touch or android back button press previous fragment is popped and displayed. How to do that?

Comment: Use the BackStack. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_2_-_managing_fragments/

Comment: I tried that but touching toolbar's back button causes my activity to finish even there are fragments on the stack.

Comment: Because you need to override `OnBackPressed()` in the `SetNavigationOnClickListener` for the Toolbar and if  `SupportFragmentManager.GetBackStackEntryCount()` returns 0 entry, call `Finish`, otherwise, one or more fragments in the BackStack call `Super` (I'm not familiar with Xamarin methods name but it's the same approach ^^)

Comment: The Toolbar back button operates much differently than the hardware back button, in other words, it is "Up vs Back" -- https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem. When I touch back button of my Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar then my activity finishes no matter whether there are fragments on the stack. However, I can confirm, that navigating through HW back button works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by overriding OnOptionsItemSelected in my activity:

```
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount == 0)
        {
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStack();
        return true;
    }
```

Note: No need to override OnBackPressed.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() { //or use on menu item clicked
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```